# How to detect a specific warning in python via OLS Regression output summary

Tags: python, numpy, warnings, statsmodels

Note: This is NOT a duplicate because one of the posts does not reference how to find my specific error with if statement implementation as I want. (two warnings and detection of only one of them)

How can I detect a specific warning in the OLS regression output so that I can utilize it in a if statement to do another regression?

There is another warning which I want to ignore, so I just want to pay attention to the specific warning:

`[2] The smallest eigenvalue is 0. This might indicate that there are strong multicollinearity problems or that the design matrix is singular.`

Ex: Warning [2] shown below the image.
[image]

What I am looking for is the simplest way to implement something like this pseudo code below:

```
If (OLS output has Warning [2])
         do something.........
```

Note: This is NOT a duplicate because one of the posts does not reference how to find my specific error with if statement implementation as I want. (two warnings and detection of only one of them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't an attribute of the results object which will contain the warnings. This is because the warning text is generated on the fly when the `summary` method is called. (See [here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/statsmodels/regression/linear_model.py#L2106) for the relevant code)

Instead you will have to check the value of the smallest eigenvalue yourself. The limit on the smallest eigenvalue that `statsmodels` uses is 1e-10 so the equivalent code for you would be:

```
if results.eigenvals[-1] < 1e-10:
    #Do something.......
```

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try!